# How to filter a lookup field in Sharepoint?

Tags: c#, sharepoint

I have a list "Contracts", it has two columns - "Title" and "Status". Status is a choice field which can be either "Active" or "Closed".
I have another list, in which I create a lookup field "Contract", which gets populated by records from the "Title" column in the "Contracts" list.
Now, I need to make it get populated only by those titles that have an active status.

So far I have this

```
            SPList contractList = web.Lists.TryGetList("Contracts");
            if (contractList != null)
            {
                myList.Fields.AddLookup("Contract", contractList.ID, false);
                SPFieldLookup lookup = (SPFieldLookup)taskList.Fields["Contract"];
                lookup.LookupField = contractList.Fields["Title"].InternalName;
                lookup.Update();
            }
```

Obviously, it gets all the titles from the "Contracts" list. Is it possible to filter it, to only show the ones with the "Status" field equal to "Active"?

Answer (score -1):

You could use query to filter the data at the time of retrieval from list..
this might help you:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms457534.aspx

Comment: I do not retrieve any data manually from the list, it does so automatically with the lookup field, that's the whole idea. Of course, I could use a query or do it manually via a loop, but that's not what I am looking for. A user needs to be able to associate a task with an active contract, but I do not want to create a custom item edit form, I want to use Sharepoint's own edit/view form and have an ability to associate an element in the task list with an active contract.